# Use different VersionCode for Debug/Release android gradle build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'd like to apply **different VersionCode to make apk** file.
For debug only fix it to `1`, and for release whatever number specified in defaultConfig.

Below code gives `mypackage-release-1.apk` file as **assembleRelease** artifact, which is not expected. I expected `mypackage-release-10111.apk` for that.

why the line `debug { defaultConfig.versionCode=1 }` affects assembleRelease artifact?

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 10111
    versionName '2.5.4'
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        project.ext.loadSign = false
        defaultConfig.versionCode = 1 // Why this value applied to assembleRelease?
    }
    release {
        project.ext.loadSign = true
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def file = output.outputFile
                output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an updated version:

```
android {
  defaultConfig { ... }

  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name == 'debug') {
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride = 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to override the VersionName?

Comment: @serv-inc not sure, if you found the solution for overriding `versionName`, but in case you didn't, you need to use: `output.versionNameOverride = "1.0.1-mySpecialVersionName"`.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest solution is moving versionCode and versionName variables from defaultConfig to debug and release respectively.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
         // without versionCode and versionName
         ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            defaultConfig.versionCode X
            defaultConfig.versionName 'X.Y.Z'
        }
        release {
            defaultConfig.versionCode A
            defaultConfig.versionName 'A.B.C'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not working: when using this solution, the most recent values (in this case, A and 'A.B.C') will always be used.

Comment: @mxkmn true. `release` is overriding it.

Answer (score 8):

Late on the party...

The entire gradle file evaluated before any task execution, so you are basically changing the default `versionCode` while declaring `debug` configs. There is no direct way to reset `versionCode` from `buildType`, but the link on the other answer do the trick by declaring a task on build variants.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
         ...
    }
    buildTypes {
         ...
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        def versionCode = flavor.versionCode
        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            versionCode += 1
        }
        flavor.versionCode = versionCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work anymore in AGP 3+ with all the configuration/execution phase separation. Could use it for signing configs too.

Answer (score 7):

Me too, but I think `defaultConfig.versionCode` was set when `build.gradle` be compiling. It's global static variable, and assigned at compiletime, not runtime.

I think we can intercept gradle task execution, and modify `defaultConfig.versionCode` at runtime.

---

After goooooooogle, I found this one works for me: https://gist.github.com/keyboardsurfer/a6a5bcf2b62f9aa41ae2

Answer (score 7):

To use with Flavors:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
    def name = flavor.getVersionName()
    def code = flavor.getVersionCode()

    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        name += '-d'
        code = 1
    }

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionNameOverride = name
        output.versionCodeOverride = code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = 26
            output.versionNameOverride = "2.2.6"
        }
    }
}
```

put it in android{}

Answer (score 0):

So recently I had to deal with the same scenario and all the examples I could find use the `applicationVariants` property which is ill-documented imo.

So after some digging through the source code a bit, I realized that in the end `versionCode` and `versionName` properties from `ProductFlavor` get merged into the AndroidManifest which got me thinking: couldn't we just inject them by ourselves, cause we have `manifestPlaceholders` property on ProductFlavor AND on BuildType DSL objects, so I came up with this -- don't hesitate to give feedback and tell me why it's wrong

In `build.gradle(app)`

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholder = [versionCode: X, versionName: "X.Y.Z"]
        }
        release {
            manifestPlaceholder = [versionCode: A, versionName: "A.B.C"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="${versionCode}"
    android:versionName="${versionName}">
    ...
</manifest>
```