# gradle - set different versionName for different build type

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to use different `versionCode` and `versionName` for debug and release builds but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I don't want to just add suffix, I want to generate versionCode completely different between two build types. Specifically, it'd best if I can set versionCode to `getDebugVersionCode()` and `getReleaseVersionCode()` for debug and release builds, respectively. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use a solution from [here](https://gist.github.com/keyboardsurfer/a6a5bcf2b62f9aa41ae2).

According to it, it's possible to change `versionName` and `versionCode` like so:

```
android {
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->     
    def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor      
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {           
       //set properties for debug
       flavor.versionName = 'version-name-for-debug`;
       flavor.versionCode = 6;
    } else {
       //set properties for release
       flavor.versionName = 'version-name-for-relese`;
       flavor.versionCode = 8;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you are looking for is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56629326/7826494).

Also, here is the implementation from my gradle file:

```
    android {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
                //set properties for debug
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.versionNameOverride = "DEBUG-VERSION";
                    output.versionCodeOverride = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posting a link to another (relevant) answer on SO is good for a *comment*. Copying another answer (which is, essentially, what you have done here) is *never* good!

Comment: @AdrianMole, Actually the code snippet that i posted differs from the solutions in the link. Its my own implementation of the problem in one of my projects. 
I posted the link so that OP can see other solutions for the same problem.