# Android gradle - different versionCode for different buildType

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-type

We have an app that has 3 build types (alpha, beta, release) and several product flavors that are dependent on a country where the app is deployed.

I am trying to automate our gradle tasks and I can't figure out how to change version code across different buildTypes. The idea is to have version code in the form "major.minor.patch.".

My current gradle default config looks like this:

```
final VERSION_MAJOR = 0
final VERSION_MINOR = 7
final VERSION_PATCH = 1

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}"
        versionCode VERSION_MAJOR * 10000000 + VERSION_MINOR * 100000 + VERSION_PATCH * 1000
    }
```

I tried to change the versionCode in a specific buildType, but that is not possible since buildTypes don't contain this field.

I get error "Error:Cannot set the value of read-only property 'versionCode' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl." for the following function:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if(variant.buildType.name.equals("release"))
        variant.versionCode += 0
    if(variant.buildType.name.equals("beta"))
        variant.versionCode += 1
    if(variant.buildType.name.equals("debug"))
        variant.versionCode += 2
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue. I obviously can't use different flavors since we already use flavors for specifying the country.
PS: I am aware of [Use different VersionCode for Debug/Release android gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691093/use-different-versioncode-for-debug-release-android-gradle-build), but they are changing the version code in a flavor.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this. Are you *really* sure that your `versionCode` should be varying by build type? I can see wanting them to have different values, but that could just be a monotonically increasing integer per build, regardless of type. Unless you're doing tens of thousands of builds per day, you aren't going to run out of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` version codes.