# How to set the versionname in a buildType in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

I could set versioncode and versionname in flavors, but I like to set them in my build type.
Is this possible in any way ?

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
}
buildTypes {
    specialversion {
        versionCode 2      // <--- Doesn't work.
        versionName "2"    // <--- Doesn't work.
    }
}
```

Comment: you might find http://stackoverflow.com/q/28691093/794088 helpful

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help me really. I solved it with manifestPlaceholders = [versionCode:"2", versionName:"2"] and added placeholders in the AndroidManifest.xml like android:versionCode="${versionCode}". I know its not reallz recommended, but in my case its the best solution so far.

Comment: make an answer please

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html) is a complete list of field, that can be modified in `buildType`. As you might see, there aren't fields, that you need. You might at best use`versionNameSuffix`.

This should be put inside `productFlavors`:

```
defaultConfig {
    productFlavors {
        specialversion {
            versionCode 2      // <--- Doesn't work.
            versionName "2"    // <--- Doesn't work.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way. Probably not recommended, but in my case its a good solution.

I replaced values in the AndroidManifest.xml with the use of `manifestPlaceholders` in my buildvariants

```
   buildTypes {
demo {
...
            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath: "@drawable/icon", versionCode:"161", versionName:"2.37"]
        }
   }
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml has the following :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx"
    android:versionCode="${versionCode}"
    android:versionName="${versionName}"
    android:installLocation="auto">
```